How to use Revolt\EventLoop?
How to run below script using Revolt\EventLoop
use Amp\Loop;
Loop::Run(static function() {
    echo "Callback function executed!" . PHP_EOL;
})

Im tried this code but it return blank response
use Revolt\EventLoop;
EventLoop::run(static function() {
    echo "Callback function executed!" . PHP_EOL;
});

Please help me, thank you!
